# How to get detailed error from CLR Stored Procedure called in DTC transaction from SSIS Package

Tags: ssis, sqlclr, msdtc

Whenever an exception is thrown in CLR stored procedure called from a SSIS package, within a DTC transaction , the error returned to client (SSIS package) relates to DTC rather than the underlying exception.

Is it possible to have information for the underlying error returned to client?

Note: When stored procedure is run from SQL Server Management Studio, outside of distributed transaction, detailed information for underlying error is returned.

> Error: Executing the query "StoredProcedure” failed with the following
>   error: “The Microsoft Distributed Transaction Coordinator (MS DTC) has
>   cancelled the distributed transaction”. Possible reasons: Problems
>   with the query, “ResultSet” property not set correctly, parameters not
>   set correctly, or connection not established correctly.

All code running on a single SQL Server 2008 instance.

```
SSIS Package
---> Sequence Container (TransactionOption = Required )
---> Execute SQL Task (ADO.NET Connection Manager, SQLClient DataProvider)
---> SQL Server CLR Stored Procedure (No exception handling code)
---> TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required)
```

**Code Which Reproduces Issue**

The following code illustrates the issue but differs from the scenario described in the title in that client is a C# console app rather than a SSIS package

**CLR Stored Procedure**

```
using System;
using System.Transactions;

public partial class StoredProcedures
{
    [Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlProcedure]
    public static void ExceptionStoredProcedure()
    {
        using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope())
        {
            throw new Exception(@"Test exception thrown from ""ExceptionStoredProcedure""");
        }
    }
};
```

**C# Console App Client**

```
using System;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Transactions;

namespace SQLCLRTester
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope())
                {
                    string connectionString = "Data Source=.; Initial Catalog=Experiments; Integrated Security=Yes";

                    using (SqlConnection noOpConnection = new     SqlConnection(connectionString))
                    {
                        noOpConnection.Open();

                        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
                        {
                            SqlCommand command =
                                new SqlCommand()
                                {
                                    CommandText = "ExceptionStoredProcedure",
                                    CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure,
                                    Connection = connection
                                };
                            connection.Open();
                            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        }

                    } scope.Complete();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Exception caught: {0}", ex.Message);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

**Message Printed By Client**

Exception caught:  The Microsoft Distributed Transaction Coordinator (MS DTC) has cancelled the distributed transaction

Notes:

1. InnerException is null
2. If the transaction scope in either the C#
   console app or in the CLR stored procedure is removed then a DTC
   transaction is not created and the information for underlying error
   is returned .

Comment: Found work around thanks to links to articles provide by 
Bob Beauchemin (Partner, MVP)

Answer (score 0):

Found a workaround that uses SqlContext.Pipe.Send() thanks to links provided by 
Bob Beauchemin (Partner, MVP). See code below.

Notes: SqlClient  appends "information messages" sent by SQL Server to SqlException.Message so client code that uses SqlClient doesn't need to change

**CLR Stored Procedure**

```
using System;
using System.Transactions;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Server;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

public partial class StoredProcedures
{
    [Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlProcedure]
    public static void ExceptionStoredProcedure()
    {
        using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope())
        {
            try
            {
                throw new Exception(@"Test exception thrown from     ""ExceptionStoredProcedure""");
                scope.Complete();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                if (Transaction.Current.TransactionInformation.DistributedIdentifier != Guid.Empty)
                    SqlContext.Pipe.Send(ex.Message);

                throw;
            }
        }
    }


};
```

**Message Printed By Client**

Exception caught: The Microsoft Distributed Transaction Coordinator (MS DTC) has cancelled the distributed transaction.

Test exception thrown from "ExceptionStoredProcedure"

**Possible Explanation**

Based on article links found by Bob about DTC transaction abort and T-SQL TRY/CATCH I think the observed behaviour may unfold as follows:

1. Exception in transaction scope in CLR stored procedure causes a
   transaction abort vote to be sent to DTC.
2. DTC sends an abort request to all enlisted resource managers
   including SQL Server
3. SQL Server translates abort request into an attention signal to the
   SQL Server session in which  the CLR stored procedure is executing
4. Attention signal changes how SQL Server CLR hosting code treats with
   unhandled CLR exception which in turn results in exception message
   not being included in result returned to client

**Links to articles:**

http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/414969/uncatchable-error-when-distributed-transaction-is-aborted

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179296(SQL.90).aspx